# Adding up prices from an Array in Java?

Tags: java, review

I have some review questions for an upcoming test in my Java class, the one I am working on at the moment asks us to create a cafe menu with two arrays, one with menu items and the other with prices. We have to print the average of all the prices before asking the user which item(s) from the menu they want and then finally print the total of the items.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cafeMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice; 
        double total = 0;

        //Array for storing prices
        double [] cafePrice = new double[5];
        cafePrice[0]= 6.99;
        cafePrice[1]= 5.99;
        cafePrice[2]= 2.99;
        cafePrice[3]= 1.50;
        cafePrice[4]= 2.50;

        //Menu item array
        String [] cafeDrink = new String[5];
        cafeDrink[0] = "Macchiato";
        cafeDrink[1] = "Latte"; 
        cafeDrink[2] = "Americano";
        cafeDrink[3] = "Tea";
        cafeDrink[4] = "Cappichino";

        //Welcome user and gather their menu selection
        System.out.println("Welcome to our cafe! Please enjoy!");
        System.out.printf("The average pricing for our drinks is: %.2f \n", + cafeAvg( cafePrice));
        System.out.println("Please enter a menu selection:\n"
                + "0. Macchiato -- $6.99\n"
                + "1. Latte -- $5.99\n"
                + "2. Americano -- $2.99\n"
                + "3. Tea -- $1.50\n"
                + "4. Cappichino -- $2.50");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        //Add up the total
        for(int i = 0; i < cafePrice.length; i++ ) {
            if(choice == cafePrice[i]) {
                total += cafePrice[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your total is: " + total);
    }

    //Method for average menu price
    public static double cafeAvg(double[] array) {
        double sum = 0;
        double sum2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sum += array[i];
            sum2 = sum /array.length;
        }
        return sum2;
    }
}
```

I haven't set up a do while loop just yet to continue to ask the user for input because I've sort of gotten stuck with adding the prices together. I'd imagine I've made an error in my for loop, or possibly a logic error? 
This is the result I keep getting, regardless of the choice made:

> Welcome to our cafe! Please enjoy!
>   The average pricing for our drinks is: 3.99
>   Please enter a menu selection:
>   0. Macchiato -- $6.99
>   1. Latte -- $5.99
>   2. Americano -- $2.99
>   3. Tea -- $1.50
>   4. Cappichino -- $2.50
>   4
>   Your total is: 0.0

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: read carefully your `cafeAvg` method. Are you 100% sure of what it is doing ? Use debugger (or paper+pen) to clearly observe the evolution of your variables during the execution of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the following incorrectly,

```
    if(choice == cafePrice[i]) {
        total += cafePrice[i];
    }
```

choice is an int while cafeprice[i] is a double ... moreover they represent different things. You actually want to do the following I think,

```
total += cafePrice[choice];
```

instead of the whole for loop.

This code works for me,

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice; 
    double total = 0;

    //Array for storing prices
    double [] cafePrice = new double[5];
    cafePrice[0]= 6.99;
    cafePrice[1]= 5.99;
    cafePrice[2]= 2.99;
    cafePrice[3]= 1.50;
    cafePrice[4]= 2.50;

    //Menu item array
    String [] cafeDrink = new String[5];
    cafeDrink[0] = "Macchiato";
    cafeDrink[1] = "Latte"; 
    cafeDrink[2] = "Americano";
    cafeDrink[3] = "Tea";
    cafeDrink[4] = "Cappichino";

    //Welcome user and gather their menu selection
    System.out.println("Welcome to our cafe! Please enjoy!");
    System.out.printf("The average pricing for our drinks is: %.2f \n", + cafeAvg( cafePrice));
    System.out.println("Please enter a menu selection:\n"
            + "0. Macchiato -- $6.99\n"
            + "1. Latte -- $5.99\n"
            + "2. Americano -- $2.99\n"
            + "3. Tea -- $1.50\n"
            + "4. Cappichino -- $2.50");
    choice = input.nextInt();

    //Add up the total
    total += cafePrice[choice];
    System.out.println("Your total is: " + total);
    }

    //Method for average menu price
public static double cafeAvg(double[] array) {
    double sum = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
        sum2 = sum /array.length;
    }
    return sum2;
}
```

Comment: This yields the same results, total is still displaying as 0.0. Have I not populate the array correctly?